# Tableview Reload not working for a Parent VC / Child VC scenario

Tags: uitableview

I have a scenario where my tableview reload is not working. Please let me know  if I have modeled my design correctly or I need to change it.

- I have a core view controller and each tab bar view controller is inherited from this core view controller
- Each of the tab bar view controller has a tableview and implements the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource protocol.
- If the app is launched for the first time, In core view controller's viewDidLoad , I have a method to fetch data from web. In the child view controller's viewDidLoad method I have a method which populates the data source for the tableview.
- So the issue is on the first launch, data is fetched and saved successfully in Core data but it does not reload the tableview so its empty.

So Currently as per the below code, on First launch I see the Alert view then the loading view and I see the data getting saved in Core Data. But the first tab bar's table view loads up empty with no data and the reason being, its [reload is not being called]. But on next launch the data is there.

Below is the code

Core View COntroller

---

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      if (!self.myManagedObjectContext) {

    //Get Shared Instance of managedObjectContext

    self.myManagedObjectContext = [LTDataModel sharedInstance].mainObjectContext;

    //Check if managed object context has required data

    ......    
    if (<data not found> {
        [self fetchDataIntoContext];
    }
}


 -(void)fetchDataIntoContext {
       UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Initializing..."
                                                  message:@"This is your first launch of App"
                                                 delegate:nil
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
      [message show];
      UIView *loadingView = [[UILoadingView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
      [self.view addSubview:loadingView];
      dispatch_queue_t fetchEventQ = dispatch_queue_create("Fetcher", NULL);
      dispatch_async(fetchEventQ, ^{
           <add data to core data>
        [[LTDataModel sharedInstance] save];
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [[self.view.subviews lastObject] removeFromSuperview];
      });
  });
}
```

Child View Controller

---

```
 --(void)setMyArrayOfEvents:(NSMutableArray *)myArrayOfEvents {
     if (_arrayOfMyEvents != arrayOfMyEvents) {
       _arrayOfMyEvents = arrayOfMyEvents;
        [self.eventTableView reloadData];
     }
  }

 -(void) viewDidLoad {  
     [super viewDidLoad];

   //Get Shared Instance of managedObjectContext if it does not exist
    if (!self.myManagedObjectContext) {
        self.myManagedObjectContext = [LTDataModel sharedInstance].mainObjectContext;
     }
    //Populate the array which feeds the tableview
    [self populateTableViewArrayFromContext];
  }

  -(void)populateTableViewArrayFromContext
  {
      <Fetch data dfrom Core Data ......>

      self.myArrayOfEvents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:localArray];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. The issue was not with Child VC's viewDidLoad not being called. Before the background fetching of data finishes the loading view is removed.

Hence the solution was I added the function that populates the data source arrays in the core (parent) view controller with empty body. The Child VC implements the functionality. And called the method before I remove the loading view. Look at code below that I changed in coew view controller

CORE VIEW CONTROLLER

---

```
 -(void)fetchDataIntoContext {
        UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Initializing..."
                                              message:@"This is your first launch of App"
                                             delegate:nil
                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];
     [message show];
     UIView *loadingView = [[UILoadingView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
     [self.view addSubview:loadingView];
     dispatch_queue_t fetchEventQ = dispatch_queue_create("Fetcher", NULL);
     dispatch_async(fetchEventQ, ^{
          <add data to core data>
        [[LTDataModel sharedInstance] save];
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
          **[self populateTableViewArrayFromContext];**
         [[self.view.subviews lastObject] removeFromSuperview];
     });
  });
}
   -(void)populateTableViewArrayFromContext {
        //empty the implemetation is in Child VC
    }
```